# Null values in database table when creating an entity

Tags: java, database, ejb, entity, message

I am using a message driven bean to create an entity and add it into the database.

However, the values become null when I create the entity and persist it into the database.

[image]

My code to create the entity.

```
public void createSuggestion(Date date, String content) {
        System.out.println("Suggestion Content is " + content);
        System.out.println("Suggestion Date is " + date.toString());
        SuggestionEntity suggestion = new SuggestionEntity();
        suggestion.create(date, content);
        em.persist(suggestion);
           }
```

This is the System.out.println result.
Suggestion Content is Hello. This is a test.
Suggestion Date is Tue Oct 22 20:28:39 SGT 2013

However, they became null when entered into the database.

The code for my Suggestion Entity is too long.
So I have included it below in the pastebin link.
http://pastebin.com/YMcknQTC

Any help please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
   public void create(Date date, String content) {
        this.setSuggestionDate(suggestionDate);
        this.setSuggestionContent(suggestionContent);
    }
```

should look like this:

```
   public void create(Date date, String content) {
        this.setSuggestionDate(date);
        this.setSuggestionContent(content);
    }
```

Comment: Omg! What a silly mistake! Thanks! =D
Accepting your answer in 7 mins.